# Junction links in windows 8 for ssd

Tags: windows, windows-8, ssd

Hello i have an asus s550cm and i have a 24gb Kingston ssd, i installed Windows 8 and i have a problema with junction links.

The only junction link i can make it´s users folder but when i try to remove

-ProgrData
-Program files
-Program files (x86)

I can´t even when i enter Command line after and before configuring Windows
I use:

```
robocopy "c:/program files" "d:/program files" /E /COPYALL /XJ
rmdir "C:/program files"
mklink /J "c:/program files" "d:/program files"
```

Comment: Of course. These folders will always be in use. You'd have to do this from another Windows instance.

Comment: @DanielB Also possible with the Windows RE (aka Windows recovery disks).

Answer (score 1):

A backup before you try this might be a good idea, just in case...

Boot into recovery mode. 
 - Open the charms menu
 - Click Settings
 - Click Power
 - **Hold Shift** and click restart
 - On the *Choose an option* menu click Troubleshoot
 - On the *Troubleshoot* menu click Advanced options
 - On the *Advanced options* menu click Command Prompt
 - You will be asked to select a user and enter your password

You should now be at a Windows RE (Recovery Environment) command prompt running on drive X:
The files on C: will not be locked by the OS.
Switch to C: drive and perform your actions.

One caveat here is that C:\ProgramData contains junctions and at least one of them is recursive. ("C:\ProgramData\Application Data" points back "C:\ProgramData"). Robocopy won't copy junctions as is. It can either expand them or ignore them. This will cause you all sorts of problems. To work around this:

- Use "dir /s /AL" and make note of all links in your source directories.
- Use the /XJ flag in robocopy to exclude junctions.
- Then manually restore all the links in your new location with mklink.

If you still have trouble deleting those directories after your copy you may have to take ownership and/or change permissions using takeown,icacls, and attrib - e.g:

- takeown /f C:\ProgramData /r /d y
- icacls C:\ProgramData /T /Grant Administrators:F
- attrib /S /D -S -H -R C:\ProgramData

<strike>One thing you can try is booting into "Safe Mode with Command Prompt"-
see [Windows Startup Settings (including safe mode)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/windows-startup-settings-including-safe-mode)- 
and run your commands there.</strike>

<strike>Safe mode may. (may!) Not lock the files that are preventing you from removing these directories.</strike>

Comment: It does lock the files